# API 2 Controller not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm not sure why but my api route just isn't working? What I do is click on the add controller, select Web API 2 controller with actions using EF (so that it builds it for me) select the model and context and click Add.

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**ProductsController (ApiController)**

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.Products;
    }
```

This would imply that by going to /api/products it would display a json format of products ... it doesn't. What I DO get is a 404: The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. I tried putting a breakpoint in too and that doesn't even get hit. So I'm a little confused.

I do have custom Web Route configs, which I thought could have been the problem, but when commenting them out still this happens. Is scaffolding missing something?

Thanks for any help

Comment: In the official examples they use `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. maybe this is the issue?

Comment: Did you add/create the WebApiConfig after the project was created? If so, did you remember to add it to the Global.asax where the other registration events occur? It's worth a check if you manually tried to setup the Web API after the project was created.

Comment: I believe it was automatically scaffolded for me. What do I need to look for in the Global.asax file? I have  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes) but nothing specifically for API. Could that be the problem?

Comment: SORTED! Thank you Nick for pointing me in the right direction. It was indeed something to do with Global.asax file. I have updated the question with the fix

Comment: Don't post the solution in the question and put "RESOLVED" in the title. Post it as an answer and accept it. Then fix your title so it actually describes the problem.

Answer (score 21):

After creating a new project and creating an API controller a text file popped up (One i decided to close thinkign I knew better) But it does not pop up again once closed.

**The Solution**

Simply add 2 using statements to Global.asax

```
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;
```

and GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); **MUST COME FIRST** in the same file under the Application_Start method

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // <--- this MUST be first 
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Hopefully this can help someone else out

Comment: Same... I copied the line and closed the file. It is clearly written to put it at the beginning of Application_Start(). Thanks for answering your own post.

Answer (score 1):

A little addition to Ultigma's answer. In your global.asax.cs this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

should be prior to this:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

The reason is that the default Web Api route *"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"* is more specific than the MVC default route *"{controller}/{action}/{id}"* and should be placed first. If not, a request to */api/products* will be treated as a call to a ***Products*** method of an ***Api*** controller.